# How do I automate running a batch command with 3 arguments in C# (MVC 3)?

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, automation

I have this command in process.bat file
This file takes 3 arguments - %1 = input file path %2=output path %3=output file name

This is how I call it in command prompt:

```
C:apps\xyz\>process.bat "c:\files\uploads" "c:\files\output" "123"
```

This creates 2 files: c:\files\output\abc.mp4 and c:\files\output\123.jpg using FFMPEG
Things work fine if I run in command prompt.

```
@echo off 
set w=480 
set h=320 
for "%%a" in ("%1\*.avi") 
do (ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -movflags +faststart -preset slow -crf 22 -b:v 500k -vf "scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -threads 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k "%2/%%~na.mp4" -vf select="not(mod(n\\,10))" -r 1 -t 1 -ss 3 -s sqcif "%2\%3.jpg")
```

But I need to automate this process. So I want a scheduled job or some other process that will process file periodically or when there are files to process.

I was thinking to create a C# Console app that will run every x minutes.
Console app will pass the 3 parameter to the bat file and run it.
But I am having nightmare with the console app. It just doesn't work. 
I never see the files generated nor any error given.

What will be the best practice to implement this automation in windows os (C#, MVC 3)?

Here is what I tried that never worked:

```
public static string RunBatchFile(string fullPathToBatch, string args) {            
    using (var proc = new Process {
        StartInfo =
        {                                        
            FileName = fullPathToBatch,
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            RedirectStandardError = false
        }
    })
    {
        try {
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();                   
        } catch (Win32Exception e) {
            if (e.NativeErrorCode == 2)
                return "File not found exception";
            else if (e.NativeErrorCode == 5)
                return "Access Denied Exception";
        }
    }

    return "OK";
}
```

Comment: I have it working after trying many hours. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: So what did you do to get it working? You should provide the answer so others can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

You're close. WaitForExit only throws Win32Exception if "The wait setting could not be accessed" according to the docs (Not too sure what that means). What you really want is to check the ExitCode property of proc as in:

```
switch(proc.ExitCode) {
  case 0:
    return "OK";
  case 2:
    return "File not found exception";
  case 5:
    return "Access Denied Exception";
  default:
    return "Unknown exception";
}
```

Comment: After processing a folder through this console app (using the FFMPEG to process) I am unable to delete the file from the folder. It says the file is still open in ffmpeg.exe. I am calling process.Close() and process.Displose(). Any clue if I am missing anything?